# VBS Error, Can't execute a query using WMI Service?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, wmi

I'm getting `Incorrect Syntax Near ')'`

The line it references is `oCN.Execute(sSQL)` towards the very end.

Syntactically, if I remove either line within `For Each objItem in colItems` it will not throw an error.

Is it not possible to execute a SQL query using objects from the WMI Service? Or am I making an error somewhere else?

I can list more code upon request; i'm trying to keep it simple for now.

```
Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
sCN =  "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & oRS("sql_server_instance") & ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
oCN.Open sCN

'Gather disk information from WMI Service
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & oRS("sql_server") & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = oWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Volume")

'Loop through all disks    
For Each objItem in colItems

sSQL="insert into HDS_DBA_DB.[dbo].[TEMP_disk_info_table] (drive_letter, capacity) " &_
"values('" & objItem.DriveLetter & "'," & objItem.Capacity & ")"

oCN.Execute(sSQL)

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems which the problem is in the `objItem.Capacity` property, check the value of this property before to insert because the value can be empty and that produces an incorrect SQL sentence like

```
insert into HDS_DBA_DB.[dbo].[TEMP_disk_info_table] (drive_letter, capacity) values ('E:',)
```

Comment: Correct. The syntax error must have been on SQL's end. A conditional checking for blank entries fixed this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using .Execute on ADODB.Connection objects is for retrieving results.

Have you tried using an ADODB.Command object?

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = oCN

cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandText = sSQL

cmd.Execute();
```

Comment: You may use object.Execute to execute statements. Thank you for the suggestion, however.